# Simplify these set expressions.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. (A' n B')'
2. A n (A' U B)

What reasoning was used in finding the answers to the above problems:
 Inductive or deductive?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Could you format your math using MathJax, please? In this way we all manage with the same notation and it is easier to help you. If $A$ and $B$ are two arbitrary sets, then using **deduction** we can conclude all the properties, such as $(A')'=A$, $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is deductive reasoning.
For the first, use DeMorgan's laws.
For the second, start by using distibutivity
of intersection over union:
A n (B u C) = (A n B) u (A n C).